# No value given for one or more required parameter vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I have the following code in a vb form

```
 Dim dt As New DataTable
    Dim query As String = " select [incident id] as incidentid, ([incident ID] &' '&[incident date]) as incisearch from incident where [stock supplier] =hengwei"
    Using connection As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Kevin\Desktop\Non Conformance\NonConformance.accdb")
        Using command As New OleDbCommand(query, connection)
            Using adapter As New OleDbDataAdapter(command)
                connection.Open()
                adapter.Fill(dt)
                connection.Close()
            End Using
        End Using
    End Using

    If dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then
        lb_search.DataSource = dt
        lb_search.DisplayMember = "incisearch"
        lb_search.ValueMember = "incidentid"
    End If
```

I have taken the query string

```
select [incident id] as incidentid, ([incident ID] &' '&[incident date]) as incisearch 
from incident 
where [stock supplier] = hengwei
```

And ran this directly as a query in Access which returns the results as expected so I know the SQL is correct

However I am getting the following error message

> No value given for one or more required parameters.

And the following line is highlighted

```
adapter.Fill(dt)
```

Any ideas what's causing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess `hengwey` should be `'hengwey'`:

```
SELECT [incident id]                          AS incidentid, 
       [incident id] + ' ' + [incident date]  AS incisearch 
FROM   incident 
WHERE  [stock supplier] = 'hengwei'
```

I have also changed

```
([incident ID] &' '&[incident date])
```

to

```
[incident id] + ' ' + [incident date]
```

since SQL is not VB.NET (but maybe that works in Access).

If `hengwey` is actually  dynamic you should use sql-parameters to prevent sql injection:

```
Dim query As String = "SELECT [incident id] AS incidentid,  [incident id] + ' ' + [incident date] AS incisearch FROM   incident WHERE  [stock supplier] = @hengwei "
' ... '
Dim p As New OleDbParameter("@hengwei", OleDbType.VarChar, 100)
p.Value = txt_supplier.text
command.Parameters.Add(p)
' ... '
```

Comment: That has worked thanks, cant believe it was something that simple. However, now that I know that's working I have attempted to replace 'hengwei' with & txt_supplier.text & which is a textbox on the form, this now shows as " & txt_supplier.text & " and the error message returns. I have to use " instead of ' when linking to a form control. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You should write your string between double quotes, otherwise access thinks it is a parameterized query. And in your case you should change

```
 where [stock supplier] =hengwei
```

to

```
 where [stock supplier] = "hengwei"
```

If you want to use hengwei as a parameter not a constant you should add parameters to your data adapter, like this

```
adapter.Parameters.Add("@CompanyName", SqlDbType.NChar, 15, "CompanyName")
```

For more information you can use this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bbw6zyha(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Thanks, using hengwei was just a one off as I was using that to see guaranteed results, I would usually be linking it to a text box which is txt_supplier.text but now the error is back

Comment: You should use parameters, explained in the link.